# What is a difference between "used to" and 'past simple'?

Tags: grammar, past-habitual

What is a difference between:

> I used to smoke. *vs.* I smoked.
>
> I used to be a teacher. *vs.* I was a teacher.

I know that **used to** expresses a habitual action in the past but so can the **past simple**. So, what the difference?

Answer (score 3):

> I know that used to expresses a habitual action in the past but so can the past simple.

The difference is that a verb modified by "*used to*" *always* indicates a habitual action.

> I used to fight Robert.
>
> I fought Robert.

In the first example, it's clear that you fought Robert habitually. In the second example, it's possible that you fought him only one time.

Comment: OK, but it's also possible that I fought him several times in the second.

Comment: Yes, the second sentence could be either. The first can only be habitual.